# Bounds of fractional tetration

Tags: tetration, hyperoperation

I know about Kneser, but if we take a simple recursion

$$^{1/d}b=c, a(0)=b, a(n)=b^{\frac{1}{^{d-1}(a(n-1))}}$$

so

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a(n)=c$$

and we can quickly find $c$ for positive integer $d>1$ and positive $b$. But $b$ has bounds, ex.

$$d=2, \left[(\frac{1}{e})^{\frac{1}{e}}; e^e\right]$$
$$d=3, [0; \approx2,421]$$
$$d=4, [\approx0,593; \approx1,904]$$
$$d=5, [0; \approx1,762]$$
$$d=6, [\approx0,543; \approx1,689]$$
$$d=7, [0; \approx1,632]$$
$$d=8, [\approx0,511; \approx1,592]$$

What is the law of those bounds? Why is lower bound for odd $d$ is $0$?

Comment: How do you define $^xb$ for non-integer $x$?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, thank you for comment! If $^xb=c$, so $^{1/x}c=b$.

Comment: That doesn't define it though. And what's to guarantee it's uniqueness?